# Bitcoin Core initialization taking forever

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization

Today is the third day, when I'm waiting for Bitcoin Core win-x64 application will sync/initialize. How long should I wait more?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the latest version? (0.12 is much faster than earlier versions) On decent PC hardware with decent internet connection it should finish well within a day, I think.

On a PC you might want to give bitcoind a bit more memory:

```
-dbcache=<n>    Set database cache size in megabytes (4 to 16384, default: 100)
```